# Two-body decay conservation of energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, kinematics, dirac-delta-distributions, fermis-golden-rule

I was trying to derive transition rate for a two-body decay process. In one of the reference I'm following, it consider $a\rightarrow1+2$ decay, and said the daughter particles in center-of-mass reference frame have three-momenta $p*$ and $-p*$. After some mathematical steps, it says:

> Therefore,
> \begin{equation}
> \Gamma_{fi} = \frac{1}{8\pi^2m_a} \int \left| \mathcal{M_{fi}}\right|^2 g(p_1) \delta(f(p_1)) dp_1 d\Omega  
> \end{equation}
> with
> \begin{align} g(p_1)&= \frac{p_1}{4E_1E_2},\\ f(p_1) &= m_a - E_1 - E_2\\ &= m_a - \sqrt{m_1^2+p_1^2} -  \sqrt{m_2^2+p_1^2}.\end{align}
> The Dirac delta-function $\delta(f(p_1))$ imposes energy conservation and is only non-zero for $p_1=p_*$, where $p_*$ is the solution of $f(p_*)=0$ and is the momentum of daughter particle in center-of-mass frame.

I'm confused, why the center-of-mass momentum of daughter particle also made the energy conservation holds?

Notes : I'm following along mark Thomson's Modern Particle Physics, and this is on page 68.

Comment: Greetings! I'm having trouble parsing the sentence which begins with "I'm confused" and ends with a question mark. Have you perhaps omitted a word?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of [four momentum algebra.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) Given the invariant mass of the particles once the momentum is fixed the energy is also fixed.

[image]